# I lose my values in the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've organized my data using pandas. and I fill my procedure out like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_table(r'E:\빅데이터 캠퍼스\골목상권 프로파일링 - 서울 열린데이터 광장 3.초기-16년5월분1\17.상권-추정매출\201301-201605\tbsm_trdar_selng.txt\tbsm_trdar_selng_utf8.txt' , sep='|' ,header=None
,dtype = { '0' : pd.np.int})

df1 = df1.replace('201301', int(201301))

df2 = df1[[0 ,1, 2, 3 ,4, 11,12 ,82 ]]

df2_rename = df2.columns = ['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CD_NM', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD_NM', 'THSMON_SELNG_AMT', 'THSMON_SELNG_CO', 'STOR_CO'  ]

print(df2.head(40)) 

df3_groupby = df2.groupby(['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD' ])
df4_agg = df3_groupby.agg(np.sum)

print(df4_agg.head(30))
```

When I print df2 I can see the 11947 and 11948 values in my TRDAR_CD column. like below picture

[image]

after that, I used groupby function and I lose my 11948 values in my TRDAR_CD column. You can see this situation in below picture

[image]

probably, this problem from the warning message?? warning message is 'sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.'

help me plz

print(df2.info()) is

RangeIndex: 1089023 entries, 0 to 1089022

Data columns (total 8 columns):

STDR_YM_CD          1089023 non-null object

TRDAR_CD            1089023 non-null int64

TRDAR_CD_NM         1085428 non-null object

SVC_INDUTY_CD       1089023 non-null object

SVC_INDUTY_CD_NM    1089023 non-null object

THSMON_SELNG_AMT    1089023 non-null int64

THSMON_SELNG_CO     1089023 non-null int64

STOR_CO             1089023 non-null int64

dtypes: int64(4), object(4)

memory usage: 66.5+ MB

None

Comment: Btw, I cannot simulate your second problem - what is `print (df2.info())` ?

Answer (score 2):

[`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) is called first and second columns and if first level has duplicates by default it 'sparsified' the higher levels of the indexes to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes.

You can show data in first level of `MultiIndex` by setting [`display.multi_sparse`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options) to `False`.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

df.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)

print (df)
     C
A B   
1 4  7
  5  8
3 6  9

#temporary set multi_sparse to False
#http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#getting-and-setting-options
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
     C
A B   
1 4  7
1 5  8
3 6  9
```

EDIT by edit of question:

I think problem is type of value `11948` is `string`, so it is omited.

EDIT1 by file:

You can simplify your solution by add parameter `usecols` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then aggregating by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_table(r'tbsm_trdar_selng_utf8.txt' , 
                    sep='|' ,
                    header=None ,
                    usecols=[0 ,1, 2, 3 ,4, 11,12 ,82],
                    names=['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CD_NM', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD_NM', 'THSMON_SELNG_AMT', 'THSMON_SELNG_CO', 'STOR_CO'],
                    dtype = { '0' : int})


df4_agg = df2.groupby(['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD' ]).sum()
print(df4_agg.head(10))
                     THSMON_SELNG_AMT  THSMON_SELNG_CO  STOR_CO
STDR_YM_CD TRDAR_CD                                            
201301     11947           1966588856            74798       73
           11948           3404215104            89064      116
           11949           1078973946            42005       45
           11950           1759827974            93245       71
           11953            779024380            21042       84
           11954           2367130386            94033      128
           11956            511840921            23340       33
           11957            329738651            15531       50
           11958           1255880439            42774      118
           11962           1837895919            66692       68
```

Comment: Ya, but last statement I have to verified ;)

Comment: oh~~ really thanks~~ and how can i change string values into int??
I try out changing the values follow this statement
    df3 = int(df2['STDR_YM_CD']
but it's wrong

Comment: What is `print (df2.info())` ? Thanks.

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1089023 entries, 0 to 1089022
Data columns (total 8 columns):
STDR_YM_CD          1089023 non-null object
TRDAR_CD            1089023 non-null int64
TRDAR_CD_NM         1085428 non-null object
SVC_INDUTY_CD       1089023 non-null object
SVC_INDUTY_CD_NM    1089023 non-null object
THSMON_SELNG_AMT    1089023 non-null int64
THSMON_SELNG_CO     1089023 non-null int64
STOR_CO             1089023 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(4), object(4)
memory usage: 66.5+ MB
None

Comment: oh~ it's the function. haha. above is the df2.info

Comment: Thank you. You can try add `df2.STDR_YM_CD = df2.STDR_YM_CD.astype(int)`, before `groupby`.

Comment: And it seems there is some problem with your data. If data are not confidental, can you send me your csv `tbsm_trdar_selng_utf8.txt` to my email in my profile?

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks you are my fairy!!
But 
another problem pop out
They say 'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2701: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self[name] = value'
can i ignore this ??

Comment: how can i send my file to your e-mail??
I don't find your mail T.T

Comment: I send my file to you.
I changed the () to @. Is your email. right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks. Please give me a time.

Comment: I get it - unfortunately gmail it find as spam. ;)

Comment: send again?? or you get it??

Comment: I get it, I am downloading data.

Comment: I try your code and it works perfect - no lost data. So question is what is your version of pandas? `print pd.show_info()` . Is it `0.19.0` version?

Comment: oh I'm late sorry. I put print(pd.show_info)) and operate it.
I show 'module' object has no attribute 'show_info'.
is it wrong??

Comment: I type another function. print(pd.show_versions())

pandas: 0.18.1
nose: None
pip: 8.1.2
setuptools: 21.0.0
numpy: 1.11.0
IPython: 4.2.0
dateutil: 2.5.3
pytz: 2016.4
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: None
jinja2: 2.8
boto: None
pandas_datareader: None
None

Comment: Can you upgrade to last version?

Comment: Just moment ago. Really Thanks~~ you are great guy~~